JProfiler Kubernetes session with non-default namespace
I am currently trying to attach JProfiler to a kubernetes cluster/pod, to a non-default namespace. I don't seem to be able to set the namespace in the initial setup, but I don't have access to default due to corporate rules.
Is there a way to set the namespace before you try to connect to kubernetes with JProfiler?
I've tried to quick attach and I've tried to create a new session, both types of session do not seem to let you configure the namespace beforehand.

Do you see anything in the "Select remote container" dialog? It should show all namespaces in a hierarchical tree. Note that in the latest release (14.0.3) on-demand listing of pods was implemented, so you don't need rights to all namespaces. If you use an earlier version, please update to 14.0.3.

As a workaround, you can set the default namespace to the namespace that you want to profile:
% kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=myNamespace

Ha, I had discovered this shortly after posting my original question. This was the solution.  Thanks user2924975
